# jquery ajax .done if msg else

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.username').change(function(e) {
    var usr = $('.username').val()
    if(usr.length >= 4) {
        $('#status').html('<font><image src="images/loader.gif" />Checking username...</font>');

        var request = $.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:"username="+usr
        });
        request.done(function(msg) {
            if(msg == 'OK') {
                $('#status').html('<font color="green"><img src="images/accepted.png /> Available</font>');
            }
            else {
                $('#status').html(msg);
            }

        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $('#status').html(textStatus)
        });
    };
});
});

</script>
```

the script works, request.done

returnes the corect msg

msg = OK //if username is Available

msg = The username **'.$username.'** is already in use. //if the username exists

but i cant get the if msg == OK to modify the #status.....#status is left empty if msg = OK

Comment: After your request goes out, have you checked that your `msg` value is being set? I would think that it never is set to `OK` which is why that piece of your code never executes.  I"m also confused by how you setup your ajax call though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo -- missing the end-quote on the image `src`.

```
$('#status').html('<font color="green"><img src="images/accepted.png /> Available</font>');

                                                                    ^ missing " here
```

Note that there's an element-creation syntax in JQuery that can help to avoid (or at least detect) these kinds of typos:

```
var el = $("<font>", { color: "green" }).append(
    $("<img>", { src: "images/accepted.png" })
).append("Available");
$("#status").html(el);
```